# Installation of Postgreql 9.3 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: postgresql, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to install Postgresql 9.3 on Raspberry Pi and I've been running into some issues summarized [here](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/53E0EF7F.4050406@gmx.net)  and on [this blog post](https://nicolas.steinmetz.fr/blog/post/Postgresql-9.3.5-pour-Debian-Wheezy-et-architecture-armhf-%28raspberry%2C-cubieboard%2C-cubietruck%2C-etc%29).

Whenever I reach the `sudo apt-get update` step, I run into an error message:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/wheezy-pgdg/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi#
```

I'm told the [process](https://nicolas.steinmetz.fr/blog/post/Postgresql-9.3.5-pour-Debian-Wheezy-et-architecture-armhf-%28raspberry%2C-cubieboard%2C-cubietruck%2C-etc%29) works well for **cubieboard** , or **cubietruck** but fails on rpi. Is there any solution ?

Comment: Note: compiling Postgres from source does work. (takes < 30minutes)

Comment: I end up compiling from source and it took me more than one hour. But I need to enable Geo-spatial extensions from PostGis and it asks me postgresql-common and other packages which comes with the default postgresql  9.1 installation. I quit.

Comment: The GIS-extensions have a few dependencies, making it a bit harder. Once you have the compile&install scripted it works like a charm. (not yet tried it on the Pi though, only plain PostgreSQL)